Terminal command pops up constantly while debugging with Visual Studio
I got a problem since few days while debugging with Visual Studio.
Every time I try to debug my project, a blank command terminal pops up every second and close instantly. It's quite annoying because my PC focus on it.
It don't stop until I restart my PC.
I debug C# class libraries to create Revit plugins.
I use the last version of Visual Studio 2022 and I work on two PCs. They got the same config, but on the one I got the problem, I downloaded SDK kit for coding under .NET Core 8.
In a first time, I removed components from Visual Studio, finally I reinstalled it completely but the problem is still here.
I got the problem for all my projects.
Sorry if I'm not quite precise, I'm new in coding.

The terminal command pops when debugging if you configured the output type to Console Application. It seems that Debug console is integrated inside the application.
If you don't want the terminal command pops up, you can try to change the Output type of the project, from Console Application to Windows Application. For debugging, right-click your project > Properties > Application > Output type.
Note: it seems  C# class libraries cannot be debugged directly as Class Libraries are not executables and cannot be started.
Hope it can help you

Thanks for your answer. However to debug my code I launch Revit. So the type output is Class Libraries. I'm not sure the problem come from visual studio but the problem appear when I launch the debugger. Moreover, the problem stays even if I stop debugging. I have to restart my PC tu make the problem stop. At the top of the command window, its written C:\Program Files\Microsoft SO...  I don't have the following part.

Hi @TristanAndre, will the terminal command pop up if you create an other type of project or without Revit?
